# Can't make my Gzip to work

Tags: html, .htaccess, gzip

I have tried all kinds of variations but I can't can my gzip to work. **My site has simple html files** (not WP).  I admit that I'm really confused with all the different code suggestions I see. I need to know what is the right code and if the reason it's not gzipped is the code or something I need to ask the hosting to change.  Here's the code I have on my .htaccess:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|html|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 16 Apr 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</filesMatch>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#Gzip
    <ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
    </ifmodule>
#End Gzip
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't see anything wrong at the first glance. What you need to make sure though is that your host has enabled mod_gzip and / or mod_deflate for httpd. You correctly use **ifmodule** but of course that means that the instructions for those modules will only hold if they have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in some of my sites, works great with deflate. Try it:

```
# BEGIN GZIP
# mod_gzip compression (legacy, Apache 1.3)
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|xml|txt|css|js)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# END GZIP

# DEFLATE compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Set compression for: html,txt,xml,js,css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
# Deactivate compression for buggy browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Set header information for proxies
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
# END DEFLATE
```

Comment: 1. (legacy, Apache 1.3) - does 1.3 is the server version? what if my version is different?  2. same for the Mozilla versions - what about later versions?

Comment: Use [this guide](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-enable-gzip-compress-on-php-websites/) to make sure your gzip compression is enabled.